Chrome/Firefox http request timeout under Openconnect VPN (linux only)
Linux Openconnect VPN + Linux browsers:

Chrome cannot open any website. (ERR_TIMED_OUT)
Firefox can only open about 1-2 website every 5-10 seconds. (loading halt forever)
(See below) The problem only applies to linux vpn+browser combo; win32 vpn+browser is fine.

When Chrome/Firefox fails, dev tools (F12) shows the GET request to target url does not receive any response.

Other software combination, with same Openconnect VPN on same linux machine:
Linux native:

All command-line tools I used worked fine. (git,ssh,etc.)

Virtual machine: linux host + Windows 10 @ VMWare Workstation 17:

linux host vpn + win32 guest firefox: network ok.
linux host vpn + win32 guest chrome: network semi break, timeout is frequent but not always.
win32 guest vpn + win32 guest chrome/firefox: network ok.

So it is clear that VPN network (server) is not the cause, it is the client software issue.

Software version:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Linux 6.5.0-44-generic
network-manager                                             1.36.6-0ubuntu2                                                amd64        network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
network-manager-openconnect                                 1.2.6-4                                                        amd64        network management framework (OpenConnect plugin core)
network-manager-openconnect-gnome                           1.2.6-4                                                        amd64        network management framework (OpenConnect plugin GNOME GUI)
openconnect                                                 8.20-1                                                         amd64        open client for various network vendors SSL VPNs

Chrome 126/Firefox 128

The solution (or workaround) is to disable http3 on firefox/chrome.
Enabling http3 cripples (firefox) or completely breaks (chrome) http requests even when the site does not use http3 at all.
Disabling http3 also makes firefox page loading several times faster for some websites, under my vpn.
